# Homebrew installed python on mac returns weird response including "line 1: //: is a directory" & "line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

When I run `python3` I get the following

```
 % python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3: line 1: //: is a directory
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3: line 3: //: is a directory
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3: line 4: //: is a directory
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3: line 5: //: is a directory
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3: line 7: `����
                                        0� H__PAGEZERO�__TEXT@@__text__TEXT;�__stubs__TEX>�
           __cstring__TEXT�>��>__unwind_info__TEXT�?X�?�__DATA_CONST@@@@__got__DATA_CONST@�@�__DATA�@__bss__DATA�H__LINKEDIT����M4���3���0���0
                                                              PP�% 
                                                                   /usr/lib/dyldY*(�;��g�g�2 
     x

      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Python
                8d'/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib&��)�� ��H����_��W��O��{������ �'X�C���`5�� �
          @������������������������T��J�_8� �_�qA��T�   ��*@8_���i � @�� ��<���R�� " ��3����5�! �����R�����0 Ձ` ը���` ��p ��R�R�� �BT�^ յ �����@99� Ձ] ��������9�\ ����R�Ri� �Tc������� �0 աZ �"�R{�t��
                                               ��C�� @��C���������_���!0 � �RN�����O��{������W���=��45�� �r�����#���!�RN�1T�@���T��RI���)��35�{B��OA�����_��
                                                                            � X@�p �A�R"�R(� �R#���{����
��@���'�{�����   �@�R    � �R��{����a
```

Trying to check the version with `python3 --version` returns the same thing

The error appears to happen randomly, it was not happening for a while (after installing python3.10 and then later python3.11 again), and then randomly started happening again one day

---

```
% od -tx1 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 | head -n 5
0000000    2f  2f  20  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d
0000020    2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d
*
0000100    2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  2d  0a
0000120    0a  2f  2f  20  50  4c  45  41  53  45  20  44  4f  20  4e  4f

% file /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3: data
```

Comment: What are the first few bytes of `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`? It looks like it was corrupted.

Comment: @tripleee I don't know how to check that? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling `python3` though

Comment: What's the output of `od -tx1 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 | head -n 5`? What's the output of `file /opt/homebrew/bin/python3`?

Comment: (Please don't respond in comments; then we have to post another comment to tell you to delete the comment and repeat the request to [edit] the question instead.)

Comment: @tripleee well I have to post a comment anyway, or else you won't know that I updated the question

Comment: @Sam Question following takes care of that!

Comment: Your Python interpreter is corrupted. Try uninstalling it and installing it afresh.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've already done that (i think) I just uninstalled python3 and reinstalled it

Comment: The first bytes of your file are `// -------` and `// PLEASE DO NO`.  I'm guessing it's warning you about how you should handle this.  Read it.

Comment: Following on from Tim's top advice, use `more /opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks, it looks like when I build some other program, it's injecting some lines into the top of my `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`. I know where to look now to fix this

Comment: @TimRoberts I opened up my python binary and removed the first 7 lines, because they were being injected into the file somehow when they weren't supposed to be there. You're comment helped me figure this out though, thanks.

Comment: I think the method that was causing the injection was this https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/b7d8b79bcf4f4a832a155c0255d4b8a8ba23c0ad/build/transpile.js#L2787 but I don't know how. When I ran `console.log` for `jsFolder` and `jsFilePath` all that printed were files within that local js folder, and not `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` although there were some files in there like `js/python/.tox/qa/bin/python3.11`, because it looked like I had a folder named `js/python` within that directory

Comment: @TimRoberts If you post an answer version of your comment, you'll get the bounty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the hex dump, the first bytes of your file are `// -------` and `// PLEASE DO NO`.  It seems pretty clear that the file is warning you about how you should handle things.